# Screenshot with Galaxy Note 4

Tags: screenshots, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm having difficulty taking a screenshot my galaxy note 4.

I'm doing the power button + home button method.

I press and hold the power button slightly before I start pressing and holding the home button.

What this does is brings up the google voice command screen (as if I've just held the home button).

Any suggestions for resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

Put the side of your hand on the left side of the screen and swipe to the right. That should do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a reasonably good solution. Feels awkward doing it though. :)

Comment: You can also use your stylus to take screen shots (just press button on stylus and long press with it on note 4 device ).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to take a screenshot with the galaxy note 4 :

1. As [@MythrilMagician](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/111080/mythrilmagician) mentioned it, by putting the side of your hand on the left side of the screen and swipe to the right.
2. As [@reachrk](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/108847/reachrk) said, by using the stylus. Press the stylus buton, then select the last option of Air Command : Screen write. [See here](https://www.androidpit.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4-review).
3. You can also try to press Home button + Power button for 1-2s.